# Pipe sed to diff

Tags: macos, sed, diff, pipe

I want to see the `diff` between a paragraph in the middle of a file and a file containing a single paragraph.

The paragraph is on line `60` of file `foo`, and file `bar` contains only that paragraph with possible minor differences.

I can extract that paragraph using `sed` thusly: `sed -n 60,60p foo`. How can I use this in `diff`?

The following *don't* work:

```
sed -n 60,60p foo | diff bar # diff: missing operand after `foo`
diff bar `sed -n 60,60p foo` # diff: extra operand `in`
```

I can do:

```
sed -n 60,60p foo >> tempfile; diff bar tempfile
```

Is there a solution that doesn't require me to store somewhere temporarily using a pipe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use a '-' as file argument, `diff` will read from stdin:

```
  sed -n 60,60p foo | diff bar -
```

Comment: And not only `diff`; the pseudo-filename `-` signifies standard input in a lot of contexts, including, but not limited to, the GNU `coreutils`, Perl, and (often) Python.

Answer (score 11):

You could use process substitution:

```
diff bar <(sed -n 60,60p foo)
```

This can also be used to compare the output from two processes:

```
diff <(sed -n 60,60p bar) <(sed -n 60,60p foo)
```

Comment: this is pretty useful to know

Comment: @thepickle: It does here

Comment: @Thor hmm so for me when I entered it in the terminal it worked. i create a temp.sh file. and ran the file it gave me 
```
./temp.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('
./temp.sh: line 1: `diff <(sed -n 1,5p abc.txt) <(sed -n 1,5p def.txt)'
```

Comment: @thepickle: You are probably executing the script with dash or similar. Use bash